# Android - Keyboard hides editText

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my xml and I don't get that keyboard does not hide edittext.

I almost try everything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows = "true"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <!-- "ActionBar"  -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows = "true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/he">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="28dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:background="@drawable/titlebar_back_selector"
                android:id="@+id/title_bar_left_menu"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_nombre_juzgado"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:text="Malaga"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_xlarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#DCDCDC"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_top"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/informations_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/header"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_nuevo"
                    android:layout_height="50dp">



                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/above_divider"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:weightSum="4">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Pedro Martinez Duran"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="3.4"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium_large1"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_difunto"
                            android:textColor="@color/white_transparent" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_expediente"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="458"
                            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.60"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium_large1"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                            android:textColor="@color/white_transparent" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_lista_comentarios"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/footer_section"
                android:layout_below="@+id/informations_container"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#EEEEEE" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/footer_section"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp">

                <EditText
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
                    android:id="@+id/et_mensaje"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_nuevo1"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.8"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:hint="Escribe un comentario"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
                </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <com.special.utils.UICircularImage
                    android:id="@+id/bt_enviar"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:src="@drawable/enviar"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    app:background_color="@color/white"
                    app:line_color="@android:color/white"
                    app:line_color_press="@color/theme_color"
                    app:line_width="0dp"
                    app:padding="0dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".matias.fragments.ActivityComentariosPartida.ActivityComentariosPartida"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail_view"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeTrans"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `adjustPan` value for `android:windowSoftInputMode` in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
</activity>
```

`adjustPan` value is explained on the official Android website as:

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft